# ActionBlock never completes on Faulted State

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I am trying to make a simple program to better understand [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library). I am trying to create a long running task that will restart a dataflow block if it has completed.

My current `RestartActionBlock` Task is able to await completion of the `ActionBlock` if I explicitly call complete on the block by entering "-1". But when I try to raise an exception to fault the block or call the blocks Fault() interface method, the `ActionBlock`'s Completion Task never completes. In this situation the `await singleTestFlow.Completion;` call never continues.

After raising the Exception or calling the Fault() method, I can be sure the block is in the faulted state by trying to enter another input into the program and debugging the code to see that the block is in the faulted state:

[image: ActionBlock in the faulted state]

If the block is in the faulted state, why did the `await singleTestFlow.Completion;` never return?

```
class Program
{
    private static ActionBlock<string> singleTestFlow;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //start thread that should restart a completed action block
        Task.Run(RestartActionBlock);

        Console.WriteLine("Enter -0 to exit, -1 to complete flow, -0- to throw an exception, Anything else otherwise");
        var input = Console.ReadLine();

        //allow user to input text until "-0" is entered
        while (!input.Equals("-0"))
        {
            if (input.Equals("-1"))
            {
                singleTestFlow.Complete();
            }

            singleTestFlow.Post(input);

            input = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        async Task RestartActionBlock()
        {
            var iterations = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                singleTestFlow = new ActionBlock<string>(s =>
                {
                    if (s.Equals("-0-"))
                    {
                        //throw new Exception("Something went wrong in here");
                        ((IDataflowBlock)singleTestFlow).Fault(new Exception("Something went wrong in here"));
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine($"{iterations}: " + s);

                }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount });

                await singleTestFlow.Completion;

                var completionTask = singleTestFlow.Completion;

                var message = $"action block: {iterations} ";
                switch (completionTask.Status)
                {
                    case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
                        message += "ran to completion";
                        break;
                    case TaskStatus.Canceled:
                        message += "was canceled";
                        break;
                    case TaskStatus.Faulted:
                        message += "has faulted";
                        Console.WriteLine(completionTask.Exception);
                        break;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(message);
                iterations++;
            }
        }
    }


}
```

[image: Sample Console Entry]
The point in the console where i entered "eee" is where the faulted block debug screenshot was taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the simple fix:

Replace

```
await singleTestFlow.Completion; // Throws if Completion is faulted, breaking your loop.
```

with

```
await Task.WhenAny(singleTestFlow.Completion);
```

or

```
await singleTestFlow.Completion.ContinueWith(_ => { });
```

What the above does is *avoid* propagating the `Completion` task exception. This allows your `RestartActionBlock` loop to execute forever as you intended (as opposed to dying right after your block faults).

Ideally, however, you should not be disregarding the return values of the following two statements:

```
Task.Run(RestartActionBlock); // Unobserved Task. Usually a bad idea.
```

and

```
singleTestFlow.Post(input);
```

If you were observing the return values of the above, you'd actually notice that they start screaming for help as soon as your `ActionBlock<string>` faults.

The task returned by `Task.Run(RestartActionBlock)` transitions to `Faulted` state as soon as `await singleTestFlow.Completion` throws - but you never get notified, because you don't keep a reference to said task, or check its status.

Similarly, right after your `ActionBlock<string>` faults, subsequent calls to `singleTestFlow.Post(input)` actually return `false`, meaning that no more items get posted to the block. They are simply discarded.

Comment: Wow thanks for the help! It is working now. From your answer, I have two new questions. What is the difference between awaiting `singleTestFlow.Completion` and `Task.WhenAny(singleTestFlow.Completion)`? The latter makes my code work, but I do not understand the difference. Secondly, how could I use the task returned from `Task.Run(RestartActionBlock)`? I do not want to await its completion, because I need the rest of the code in main to continue.

Comment: If you want your `RestartActionBlock` task running forever, you need to make sure that it has comprehensive exception handling built in. If `await singleTestFlow.Completion` throws an exception (due to the block fault), `RestartActionBlock` returns immediately (much like a synchronous method would). It never progresses beyond the `await`. `Task.WhenAny` allows you to get around that because it merely returns a reference to the first completed (or faulted) task. It does not re-throw exceptions. Its effect is similar to putting `try/catch` around `await singleTestFlow.Completion`.

Comment: Had you kept a reference to the `Task` returned by `Task.Run(RestartActionBlock)`, you would notice that at some point it transitions to Faulted state, and deduce that your `RestartActionBlock` loop must have stopped. This would help you in debugging. Matter of fact, that is exactly how I personally went about diagnosing the issue, with some success.